# Odoo does not update a stored value with a new value, it updates with the previous one

Tags: python, odoo

I have a computed field named 'balance' which has store=True, computed from credit-debit formula, and I can update this from customer's payment or invoice moves with using @api.depends. The question is this -> When balance is $100.00, I try receiving payment, let's say $30.00. Credit-debit now equals $70.00, but balance isn't changed. When to receive $20.00 more, the formula equals $50.00, but balance is changed to $70.00, which is the previous value of the formula.

So, how to sync triggered actions and computed fields? Thanks in advance...

```
payment_ids = fields.One2many('account.payment', 'partner_id', string="Payments", readonly=True, copy=False)

@api.one
@api.depends('invoice_ids','payment_ids')
def _balancecalc(self):
    for record in self:
        record.balance = record.credit - record.debit

balance = fields.Float(string="Balance", compute="_balancecalc", store=True)
```

Comment: The problem probably lies in the code you wrote. Can you show it ? Because with just this description, we cannot help you.

Comment: Of course, I editted it.

Comment: And what would happen if instead of making the value depend on invoice_ids and payment_ids, it depends on credit and debit ? It's good practice to make a compute field compute when the fields that it uses for computation change because we cannot make sure that when invoice_ids and payment_ids change, it actually changes credit and debit values. Plus the value of balance is "stored" when the user saves the instance. Since all of these are fields on the record, you can show them and make sure that everything is working fine (show credit, debit and balance on the view for debugging).

Comment: For example, payment_ids is a field in account.payment, when you register a payment, for example paid by someone, our credit field value will go down. And it triggers our def. But it seems, the system triggers the def before payment approval. So our def runs with the old credit and debit values, and that does not make our balance field changed.

Comment: Ok, I found a field, move_name in account.payments. As far as I see, move_name field used after payment registeration. My model inherited from res.partner. How can I check from my class that whether if move_name field is updated? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are credit and debit stored fields ? Or are they computed as well ? Your problem seems to be the fact that changes detected on One2many or Many2many are only creation or deletion. If they are edited, the may not trigger your compute function. And calling a method on (let's say) payments will only edit the record, thus not call the recomputation. Adding a new payment triggers it, and now, the preceding payment is finally taken into account.